# How to implement global back end exception handler

Tags: grails, exception, global

I have grails application.

I want to implement global grails back end exception handler.

Means if there are any exception in application at back end like NullPointer, ArrayIndexOutOfBounds or any other exception is raised then some code should be executed. How we can do this in grails 2.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can hadle it using `UrlMappings`.
From the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.4/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings)

```
static mappings = {
"403"(view: "/errors/forbidden")
"404"(view: "/errors/notFound")
"500"(controller: "errors", action: "illegalArgument",
     exception: IllegalArgumentException)
"500"(controller: "errors", action: "nullPointer",
     exception: NullPointerException)
"500"(controller: "errors", action: "customException",
     exception: MyException)
"500"(view: "/errors/serverError")
}
```

> With this configuration, an IllegalArgumentException will be handled by the illegalArgument action in ErrorsController, a NullPointerException will be handled by the nullPointer action, and a MyException will be handled by the customException action. Other exceptions will be handled by the catch-all rule and use the /errors/serverError view.

Answer (score 0):

Use Grails declarative exception handling for controllers

```
def handleLException(Exception e) {
    render "Opps: ${e.message}"
}
```

More information here: http://docs.grails.org/2.4.5/guide/single.html#controllerExceptionHandling